# if condition with css: setting a border and removing when clicked consequently

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement

I have like and dislike objects. One it is clicked I wanna display a border around it, which works perfectly.  Then if clicked again, I want the border disappear.  I used if condition with .css but I could not get it worked.  .css("border-width") always returns empty when I print it with alert function. What could be the problem?  Everything works other than this.

```
$('a[id*="grd_WallPosts_lbtn_LikeDislike_Like"]').click(function () {

            if ($(this).children('#imgLikeDislike_Like').css("border-width") == "1px") {

                $(this).children('#imgLikeDislike_Like').css("border-width", "0px");

            } else {                    

                $(this).children('#imgLikeDislike_Like').css("border-width", "1px");
                $(this).children('#imgLikeDislike_Like').css("border-style", "solid");
                $(this).children('#imgLikeDislike_Like').css("border-color", "#b9b9b9");

                var a = $(this).attr("id");
                a = a.replace("grd_WallPosts_lbtn_LikeDislike_Like_", "");
                $('#grd_WallPosts_lbtn_LikeDislike_Dislike_' + a).children('#imgLikeDislike_Dislike').css("border-width", "0px");
            }
        });
```

Comment: as a side note- looks like you have multiple elements with id `imgLikeDislike_Like` - id must be unique in a document

Comment: what are the last 3 lines in the else block doing

Comment: can you edit the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9SJhJ/1/ to recreate the problem

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9SJhJ/2/

Comment: What I wanna do is to remove the border when clicked again to de-select it.  It does not work in the [your jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9SJhJ/2/) @ArunPJohny

Comment: which browser are you using? for me the first click is adding the border second one is removing it

Comment: Firefox.  Would this be related to jquery library version?

Comment: which is the version used? also the environment used... I'm on Windows 7 + Chrome 32

Comment: Yes FF is having a problem... need to see why... But the correct solution to this is to toggle a class like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9SJhJ/3/

Comment: @ArunPJohny, thank you.  In addition to this, I need to do this between two buttons Like vs Dislike.  When Like is clicked I wanna remove the border of Dislike, vice verse.  I updated the jsfiddle but it did not work. [here is the updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erkaner/5Y3Yc/1/)  How can I do that?

Comment: whether those two will always be next to each other

Comment: I'm asking about the physical positioning of the element, so the like and dislike `a` elements will be next to each other

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46887/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-erkaner)

Comment: yes, exactly, they will be next to each other. May I ask why does this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might use a class to set the clicked state like

```
<a class="grd_WallPosts_lbtn_LikeDislike_Like">
    <span class="imgLikeDislike_Like">Like</span>
</a>
<a class="grd_WallPosts_lbtn_LikeDislike_Dislike">
    <span class="imgLikeDislike_Dislike">Dislike</span>
</a>
```

then

```
.clicked {
    border: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
}
```

and

```
$('.grd_WallPosts_lbtn_LikeDislike_Like').click(function () {
    $(this).children('.imgLikeDislike_Like').toggleClass('clicked');
    $(this).next().children('.imgLikeDislike_Dislike').removeClass('clicked');
});
$('.grd_WallPosts_lbtn_LikeDislike_Dislike').click(function () {
    $(this).children('.imgLikeDislike_Dislike').toggleClass('clicked');
    $(this).prev().children('.imgLikeDislike_Like').removeClass('clicked');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9SJhJ/)